# Cannot convert nil to type x

Tags: go

Consider the following example:

```
    lock.RLock()
    var product *Product
    if store[productId] != nil {     //cannot convert nil to type Product
        product = &Product{}
        *product = *store[productId] //invalid indirect of store[productId] (type Product)
    }
    lock.RUnlock()
```

The exceptions are as commented per line and i don't really get what i am doing wrong..

`store` is a `map[int]Product`

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `store` as if it were declared as:

```
store := make(map[int]*Product)
```